# How can I mock or spy on the custom hook variable with jest?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using library called react-query-firebase. The custom hook useAuthUser takes firebase auth method and manages the loading state and returns firebase auth user object.

auth is a firebase method which I think that I need to mock or spy on to make sure that its not ran.

According to jest documentation it takes 2 arguments:

`jest.spyOn(object, methodName)`

in that case:

`jest.spyOn(auth,)` and what do I put as a second argument?

And what would I do with the `user` variable, mock spy or what?

```
import { useAuthUser } from "@react-query-firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./firebase";

function App() {
  const user = useAuthUser(["user"], auth);

  if (user.isLoading) {
    return <div />;
  }

  if (user.data) {
    return <User />;
  }

  return <div>Not signed in.</div>;
}

function User() {
  const user = useAuthUser(["user"], auth);

  return <div>Welcome {user.data.displayName}!</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `@react-query-firebase/auth` I use jest's `spyOn` method.

```
import * as queryFirebaseAuth from '@react-query-firebase/auth';

test('should do something', () => {
  jest
    .spyOn(queryFirebaseAuth, 'useAuthUser')
    .mockImplementation(() => ({ data: { /* your user object here */ } }));
})
```

The `spyOn` method actually mocks out the whole function so you can return anything you want.